# Is it possible to compare two similar songs given their wav files?

Tags: python, numpy, audio, scipy, pydub

I have a large library of older music (1920s, 30s, 40s, etc), with a lot of duplicates, and I'd like to determine the duplicates and organize them with the same MP3 tag information. Since the music was recorded a while ago, while they may sound similar to a human ear, their recording might actually be a bit different (quieter, more static, etc).

I'm currently parsing some of the music using `pydub` and am able to generate the wav file, remove the silence at the beginning and end of the songs, and compress the dynamic range of the music, but I'd like to be able to compare the wav files so that if they are similar enough, I can assume they are the same and give them the same tags.

Would it be possible to run the wav file data through something like `scipy` and `numpy` to compare/correlate the data with good accuracy, using something like a Fourier Transform/FFT? I know that it can be done with a system like [`dejavu`](https://github.com/worldveil/dejavu) but it's pretty intensive and uses a lot of storage in a database, and I have access to the raw files rather than using a microphone, so I'd prefer to do something that's simpler.

Comment: [beets](http://beets.io/) or [picard](https://picard.musicbrainz.org/) should be able to help you and offer much more. If you want to implement your own customized stuff, [librosa](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/index.html) could be the core (much more specialized than scipy).

Answer (score 1):

You need [audio hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#Finding_similar_records) or [acoustic fingerprint](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&pws=0&q=python+audio+fingerprinting). All of them are "intensive" (resource-hungry) as they have to unpack audio and extract data.