# Compare a fragment of an audio file to a long audio file

Tags: audio, audio-fingerprinting, audiosegment

I would like to develop a program (preferably in python, however, java or c++ would be ok too) that compares an audiofile (length around 1 to 2 seconds) to a database of audiofiles of longer duration (10 to 60 minutes). It should find the long audiofile which the small audiofile is an (almost) exact subsequence of. I know there exist some tools for that, however most require the short sequence to be a bit longer and specialize in matching a noisy sequence of music. I have also not found any libraries that seems particularly helpful. I would like to focus on speech though.
Are there tools for this (I can interact programatically with)?
Are there python libraries to this purpose, or how would I go about implementing something like that on my own?
Thank you

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49895223/how-to-compare-match-two-non-identical-sound-clips

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare / match two non-identical sound clips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49895223/how-to-compare-match-two-non-identical-sound-clips)

Comment: The answer here might be useful, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75961430/how-to-find-out-how-many-times-a-specific-audio-repeats-in-another-longer-audio/75990628?noredirect=1#comment134028993_75990628