How to detect audio retakes using Python?
I have a lot of audio recordings for lectures where I say the same thing multiple times, mostly it's incomplete statements like:
"this is the part" (and then retrying)
"this is the part where" (and then retrying)
"this is the part where we will explore the theory"
Visually in any audio or video editor, I can spot these as the waveforms look very similar i.e. the same type of high low points on the waveform.
So I am trying to use Python to do the same, so that I only keep the last retake but silence the older ones, so the audio length doesn't change. Right now my approach is like this but it gives me the exact same audio as the input.
import librosa
import numpy as np
import soundfile as sf
import os

# Load the audio file
file_path = r'C:\test.wav'
y, sr = librosa.load(file_path, sr=None)

# Parameters
chunk_duration = 1  # seconds
overlap = 0.75  # 75% overlap for better similarity matching
chunk_length = int(chunk_duration * sr)
step_length = int(chunk_length * (1 - overlap))

# List to store the indices of the last occurrence of each chunk
last_occurrence_end = 0

# Create a list to store the final audio chunks
final_audio = []

# Loop over the audio in chunks
i = 0
while i < len(y) - chunk_length:
    chunk = y[i:i + chunk_length]
    next_chunk_start = i + step_length
    
    # If this is the last chunk, just keep it
    if next_chunk_start + chunk_length > len(y):
        last_occurrence_end = len(y)
        break

    next_chunk = y[next_chunk_start:next_chunk_start + chunk_length]
    
    # Compute simple Euclidean distance between the two chunks
    distance = np.linalg.norm(chunk - next_chunk)
    
    # Set a threshold for similarity
    if distance > 1000:  # Adjust this threshold as needed
        if i > last_occurrence_end:
            final_audio.append(y[last_occurrence_end:i])
        last_occurrence_end = i + chunk_length
    
    i = next_chunk_start

# Append the last segment after the loop
if last_occurrence_end < len(y):
    final_audio.append(y[last_occurrence_end:])

# Check if any chunks were added to final_audio
if final_audio:
    # Concatenate all the kept chunks to form the final trimmed audio
    final_audio = np.concatenate(final_audio)
else:
    # If no chunks were kept, return the original audio
    final_audio = y

# Define the new file path with "_clean" suffix
new_file_path = os.path.splitext(file_path)[0] + '_clean.wav'

# Export the trimmed audio
sf.write(new_file_path, final_audio, sr)

print(f"Cleaned audio saved as: {new_file_path}")


Not having done this before, and not knowing what available tools there are. I would do some new "template" recordings of you saying the repeated phrases. I would take these chunks and run a cross-correlation on them with the original recording. See any peaks in the correlation. This is quite exhaustive if your audio signal is very big. So maybe downsample both before doing this....

Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/49960225/16815358, where there is a very nice and comprehensive answer.

you will need techniques from speech recognition. you need actual words or features that approximate syllables (spectrum and "cepstrum" and all that stuff). then you can match for that.

@TinoD the question you found asks for recommendations and the answer is a link dump. might be good enough.

NOTE: There might be solutions that require less work, using speech recognition or ready-to-use packages that do what you need.
If I was to do this by my own, for fun, I would try such idea:

Find beginnings (1-2 seconds?) of utterings. I assume each sentence is separable because of some silent pause. If not this point might need re-thinking.
Turn those signals into vectors of features. Most common is STFT + MFCC combo (scipy.signal.stft, librosa.feature.mfcc)
Calculate distance matrix between vectors of features of consecutive sentences.
Use dynamic time warping (DTW) algorithm (https://github.com/pollen-robotics/dtw) to analyse those distance matrices. You may want to search for long almost diagonal lines, that run through low-distance "pixels".


You may need to add some normalization to distances. For sure - add more weight to distances of high energy frames (so some irrelevant silent frames do not noise DTW).

thx i was thinking something similar but wasn't sure of all these steps. i guess i have to try and see if it will work. the audio is cleaned up so between sentences it's completely silent.

@JoanVenge Good luck! Let me know how it went

Also just to update speech recognition I am not sure but audio transcription like in whisper the timings are not exact so it's hard to rely on these not to mention it's not always exact.

Speech recognition is rarely meant to work very well for whispered speech. There are very few applications for whisper recognition (although that might be changing, I do not know for sure).

Whisper in this case the name of an open-source pretrained speech model
